# SFML and Netbeans. Unable to install

Tags: netbeans, installation, sfml, netbeans-8

I've been trying to install SFML in Netbeans for the last 5 hours and there is an error which I can't fix.

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2, SFML-2.1-windows-gcc-4.7-mingw-32bits and MinGW i686-w64-mingw32. My computer is a win 8.1 x32

For installing SFML I've included the include directory in the C++ compiler and the libraries in the linker. Also I've copied the SFML dll's to the project folder.

The SFML program builds but when I try to run it, it shows "ExampleProject.exe has stopped working" and I must close it. If I run from the project folder I get the error:

> "the procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located
>   in the dynamic link library sfml-system-d-2.dll"

I can build and run a C++ program so the problem may be with SFML I think.